# Question about weird behavior referencing a YAML pipeline resource using a variable for the pipeline resource name

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am experiencing weird behavior with YAML variables, parameters, and Azure pipeline resource references. The following shows the original implementation that works compared to my new implementation with a single line change that fails.

---

#### Working Implementation

**Template A** (makes a call to template B):

```
- template: Templates\TemplateB.yml
  serviceBuildResourceName: resourceName
```

**Template B** (uses serviceBuildResourceName param to get pipeline run information):

```
$projectId = '$(resources.pipeline.${{ parameters.serviceBuildResourceName }}.projectID)'
$pipelineId ='$(resources.pipeline.${{ parameters.serviceBuildResourceName }}.PipelineID)'
```

Template B goes on to use the values in `$projectId` and `$pipelineId` *(along with other values not listed here since it is irrelevant)* to successfully retrieve information about the a pipeline run from the specific pipeline resource, `serviceBuildResourceName`. Note that all pipeline resources are correctly defined at the beginning yaml file for the pipeline. **In this implementation above, everything works perfectly.**

---

#### Failing Implementation

**Template A** (makes a call to template B):

```
- template: Templates\TemplateB.yml
  serviceBuildResourceName: $(ServiceBuildResourceName)
```

**Template B** (uses serviceBuildResourceName param to get pipeline run information):

```
$projectId = '$(resources.pipeline.${{ parameters.serviceBuildResourceName }}.projectID)'
$pipelineId ='$(resources.pipeline.${{ parameters.serviceBuildResourceName }}.PipelineID)'
```

Note that the only difference is the following: instead of passing the hard-coded string into the `serviceBuildResourceName` parameter, I pass in a variable, which has the same value as before, `resourceName`. The variable is defined in an earlier template as such:

```
- name: ServiceBuildResourceName
  value: resourceName
```

---

I feel it should still work the same, but I know get the following error in my pipeline run:

```
WARNING: 2023-02-12 15:52:29.5071 Response body: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The value is not an integer.
$(resources.pipeline.resourceName.PipelineID)
```

---

I know that the variable is being correctly populated since the error message above contains "resourceName" in `resources.pipeline.resourceName.PipelineID`, as it should.

However, for reasons unknown to me, it now throughs an error. It seems like it doesn't recognize the pipeline resource, and instead recognizes it as a string.

Any help or insight here would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is because of how predefined variables work in YAML. Since `resources.pipeline...` is a predefined variable, it gets resolved at compile time. Thus, you can't use run-time defined variables like I am doing. Instead of resolving it as a predefined variable, it will get resolved to be a string at runtime.